# How to update Windows 10 UWP store certificate

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows 10 UWP application deployed to the Windows store.

When I now build, I get `warning APPX0108: The certificate specified has expired. For more information about renewing certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478`

It has been a while so that is fine, so I want to renew.

Going to the link, and to the section **Renewing a certificate**, steps 3 and 4 say to choose "Create Test Certificate". But I don't want a **test** certificate, I want one I can use to build and push a new version of the app to the store.

Does anyone know if these instructions are correct and just misleading (using the term "Test" certificate)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is the appropriate article afaict.  You use the temporary cert to debug and test your app, it is valid for a year.  The store server replaces it with the permanent one, after the package is validated.  So you only have to renew that temporary certificate, "Create test certificate" option in the IDE and the article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio will automatically create a certificate for uploading your app to the Store when you associate your app with Store at the first time or when your certificate expires.So you could re-associate your app with store to renew a App_StoreKey.pfx.

Use Visual studio to associate your app with the Microsoft Store:In Solution Explorer, right-click your project and then select **Store** > **Associate App with the Store** > **Next** >(sign in to the Microsoft Store) > **select** the **App Name** you have reserved>**Next** > **Associate**.

Comment: This just does not work for me. From VS, if I go to Project | Store | Create App Packages I get the same thing.. `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error APPX0108 The certificate specified has expired. For more information about renewing certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478. CordovaApp.Windows10 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets 3787 ` I don't want to associated it as it is already associate. So stil not sure what to do here...

Comment: When was the last time you associate app? If the last association was more than a year old, you'd better re-associate your app to get an unexpired App_StoreKey.pfx.

Comment: Thanks @Dasiy. I did the reassociation, that appeared to work, but I cannot for the  life of me see where to get a new certificate. All the doco (that I can find) is seems to just explain how to create a *test* certificate, not a proper one. I have been through this before, and cannot remember how I got the store certificate before. IF I ever find out how to do this again, I will definitely write it down this time.

Comment: If your certificate is expired, VS will automatically create a certificate that can be identified by the store after you re-associate your app with VS. This certificate is used for uploading the package to the Dev center(Store). For the app in the store, the store will automatically generate the certificate for users to use, without requiring developers to maintain it.So If you re-associate/associate your  app with Store, you are no need to create a Store certificate manually.

Comment: @ Dasiy - Thanks again. I have done the reassociation, however when I build (from VS) I still get the `warning APPX0108: The certificate specified has expired` warning. If I do a folder search for `*.pfx`, all I find is `CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx` dated over a year ago. So my problem is still how do I get this certificate? When I build outside of VS, I point to the `.pfx` file, but of course I have no new `.pfx` file to point to yet.

Comment: @peterc could you create a new test certificate to replace the expired temporarykey.pfx(double click Package.manifest>Packaging>choose certificate> configure certificate>create a test certificate>....). and then re-associate your app again to generate the App_StoreKey.pfx?

Comment: Thankyou very much. Now I am getting close! I did as you explained, and this time I got a new certificate from the store! The only problem I am having now is installing it so I can test my app build  (and get others to test) before pushing to the store. I assumed the store certificate would use the same password I used for the new temp certificate, but hen I double click to install, when I enter the same password, it reports it as invalid. Should this pick up the password from the temp certificate?

Comment: I explained this thread in MSDN, please go to[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7ba68a41-74fc-4fe5-9f77-d56872f9e591/how-to-renew-uwp-store-licence-when-it-has-expired?forum=windowsstore&prof=required]

Answer (score 5):

In short:

- Open Package.appxmanifest
- Go to Packaging tab
- Press Choose certificate
- Select Create test certificate from drop down list
- Overwrite your test certificate
- Go to Project -> Store -> Associate App with the Store, and re-associate the app so the new certificate is used.
- Voila!

Comment: I think this answer is underrated. It actually resolved my issue! Thanks :)