# UWP store app expired certificate doesn't updated by "Associate App with the Store"

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, certificate

I had the same question as next link.
[How to update Windows 10 UWP store certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379543/how-to-update-windows-10-uwp-store-certificate)
I did the same operation as the link answer. But expired old certificate still remains.
The date is 2 years ago. So I think something may have be changed. Or this works same in Visual studio 2019 newest version(16.8.2)?

I checked below things.

1. Making test certificate. It is rightly loaded instead of expired certificate.
2. Deleting expired certificate and do "Associate App with the Store". No certificate is loaded.
3. There is a different project I am now making. I create that app in Microsoft Partner Center and do "Associate App with the Store". Its certificate is successfully loaded.
4. I searched UWP document related page and Microsoft Partner Center how to update expired certificate. Nothing I can find.

Comment: The only way to renew the certificate is the re-associate the app with the Partner Center because the store will manage the certificate. If this does not work for you, the last choice is to create a new project, merge the code from the old project to the new project, and associate the new project with the store.

Comment: Thank you the answer. I will try it.

Comment: I make new project. Certificate is successfully loaded by associate. There is something wrong in my old project. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Re-associate the app with the Partner Center is the way to renew the certificate because the store will manage the certificate. If the old project failed with the step, you could create a new project and try to merge the code from the old project to the new project, then associate the new project with the store.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the steps mentioned in other answers (creating a new test certificate, then re-associating the app with the store product), I also had to delete the ".vs" and ".user" files to get things to work.

Then I was getting an error "the subject name of the provided certificate does not match the publisher name in the store association file" - to fix this, after the store association part, I had to create another certificate, and set the Publisher Common Name to the store publisher name WITHOUT the “CN=” prefix (as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/398284/experiencing-(invalid-package-publisher-name)-erro)).